# Get URL of MVC Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, selenium

I have an ASP.Net MVC web application that will be used on a number of different machines. I want to get the URL of the page as a string as I then use the Url for selenium automated testing.

I have tried using the following code:

```
public static string getUrl()
{ 
  Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
  String absoluteUrlBase =
           uri.Scheme + "://" +
           uri.Host +
           (uri.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + uri.Port);
  return absoluteUrlBase;
}
```

But get a error 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' using this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unneeded. Your error is probably due to `HttpContext` being null.

Anyway, Selenium provides this built in. You just need the `.Url` property on your driver instance, for example:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
string currentUrl = driver.Url;
```

Comment: This only get the current page. How can I redirect the driver to a different page other than the one I'm on??

Comment: @user2184530, that is a new question, please create a new one next time, but I suspect the answer to your question lies in the `driver.Navigate()` methods. Please also check out the [Selenium site](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/), both of your questions have documentation surrounding them...specifically [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_Navigate.htm) regarding the navigation.